# Providing less than operator for one element of a pair

Tags: c++, stl, operators, operator-keyword

What would be the most elegant way too fix the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

typedef map< int, int > row_t;
typedef vector< row_t > board_t;
typedef row_t::iterator area_t;

bool operator< ( area_t const& a, area_t const& b ) {
    return( a->first < b->first );
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int row_num;
    area_t it;

    set< pair< int, area_t > > queue;
    queue.insert( make_pair( row_num, it ) ); // does not compile
};
```

One way to fix it is moving the definition of less< to
namespace std (I know,  **you are not supposed to do it.**)

```
namespace std {
    bool operator< ( area_t const& a, area_t const& b ) {
        return( a->first < b->first );
    };
};
```

Another obvious solution is defining less than< for 
pair< int, area_t > but I'd like to avoid that and be 
able to define the operator only for the one element 
of the pair where it is not defined.

Comment: That's an interesting name you have for your set there ;)

Comment: What's in a name? A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.

Answer (score 7):

When you are implementing a comparator that implements some specific and/or fairly exotic comparison approach, it is better to use a named function or a function object instead of hijacking the `operator <` for that purpose. I'd say that the natural way to compare a `std::pair` object would be to use lexicographical comparison. Since your comparison is not lexicographical, taking over `operator <` might not be a good idea. Better implement a comparator class

```
typedef pair< int, area_t > Pair; // give it a more meaningful name

struct CompareFirstThroughSecond {
  bool operator ()(const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) const { 
    if (p1.first != p2.first) return p1.first < p2.first;
    return p1.second->first < p2.second->first;
  }
};
```

and use it with your container

```
std::set< Pair, CompareFirstThroughSecond > queue;
```

(I hope I deciphered your intent from your original code correctly).

You can also implement the above `operator ()` method as a template method, thus making it usable with all `std::pair`-based types with an iterator as a `second` member. It might not make mich sense though, since your comparison is "exotic" enough.

Comment: You seem to be missing that `std::pair` already implements `operator<`, and OP is wondering how to plug in a comparator for the second member (iterator).

Comment: @UncleBens: Oh, got it. You are right. Still, what I proposed should work. Also, trying to implement a comparator for iterator type through operator overloading is a risky endeavor since in general case iterator might happen to be implemented by a built-in type (for which operator overloading is not possible).

Comment: @UncleBens - that's an excellent way of putting it. I want to _plug-in_ an operator for the second element of the pair.

@AndreyT - I would need to compare the ints from the pair first and - if they are equal - go on and compare `area_t` members of the pair. That would work.



But that's precisely the solution I was trying to avoid -- `operator<` is already implemented for `std::pair` and for ints. I do not want to reinvent  the wheel. (Plus that's an awful lot of typing.)

Comment: @Koszalek Opalek: OK, but still keep in mind that if it so happens that your iterator type is a built-in type, your code will fail to compile, since it is illegal to overload operators for built-in types.

Comment: @AndreyT: You appear to have misunderstood what he was saying, but I corrected the code in the answer accordingly.